# Java equals() method - how does 'semantics of equals in subclasses' determine the use of getClass and instanceof

Tags: java, inheritance, equals

I'm a beginner in Java programming. Currently I'm reading about Inheritance and the equals method at [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1021579&seqNum=2) page.
I understand the explanations until this point:

> Compare the classes of this and otherObject. If the semantics of
>   equals can change in subclasses, use the **getClass** test:

```
if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
```

> If the same semantics holds for all subclasses, you can use an **instanceof** test:

```
if (!(otherObject instanceof ClassName)) return false;
```

I don't understand what 'semantics of equals' mean. Can someone share scenarios where we use getClass() and instanceof please?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: "Semantics of equals" just means, what's your definition for when two objects are equal?  The real important question is: if you have a class `A` that can have subclasses `B1`, `B2`, ..., then when could two objects that could be anywhere in the hierarchy be equal?  Do they have to be the exact same class?  Are you only using data defined in `A` in your definition, so that it doesn't really matter which class they're in?  The answer depends on your particular situation.

Comment: This is a tricky subject.  The article you're reading is pretty good, but here's another good one that might help explain things a little better: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @ajb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, getClass() returns the immediate class of the object. for example,

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }
```

if we create two objects from A and B,

```
A objA = new A();
B objB = new B();
```

now we can check how getClass work

```
System.out.println(objA.getClass()); //Prints "class A"
System.out.println(objB.getClass()); //Prints "class B"
```

So,

```
objA.getClass() == objB.getClass()
```

returns false. But

```
System.out.println(objB instanceof A); //Prints true
```

This is because instanceof returns true even if a superclass is given of the provided object.

So, when you design your equals() method, if you want to check the given object(otherObject) is instantiated from the same immediate Class, use the

```
 if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
```

If it is okay that the given object(otherObject) is made even from a subclass of a Class (ClassName) you provide, use

```
if (!(otherObject instanceof ClassName)) return false;
```

Simply, "semantics of equals" means "The purpose you expect from equals() method". So you can use the appropriate method according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

> changing semantics of equals

It means that may be the equals method can be overwritten in subclasses, in such scenarios use getClass to check whether objects belong to same class.

> In general, getClass vs instance of

We use getClass when we need to know the class of a particular object. Consider cases when there is linear chain of Inheritance as follows:

MainClass -> SubClassLevel1 -> SubClassLevel2

and initialize as

```
MainClass mc = new SubClassLevel2();
```

Here to know that which class in the hierarchy is the class of our object.

Now, instance of method is used in the cases where you have to merely check that whether x is an instance of class Y or not. It returns boolean.

Hope this answers your query :)